# Dynamically access property of property of struct

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, mirror

I have a large numbers of structs and all of them have `responseId: String` and there is a property with same name as the value of `responseId` that contains `contactId: String`.

- `responseId` is always non-optional String.
- `contactId` of inner object is also non-optional String
- all inner objects are optional (at runtime only one of the objects will be non-nil)

Below are two examples:

```
protocol ContainerBase {
    var responseId: String { get }
}

struct Container1: ContainerBase {
    struct OtherA {
        let contactId: String
        let cats: [String] // Other info here, not related to OtherB
    }
    struct OtherB {
        let contactId: String
        let dogsNum: Int // Other info here, not related to OtherA
    }
    let responseId: String
    let otherA: OtherA? // Optional
    let otherB: OtherB? // Optional
}

struct Container2: ContainerBase {
    struct AnotherA {
        let contactId: String
        let passed: Bool  // Other info here, not related to AnotherB
    }
    struct AnotherB {
        let contactId: String
        let friend: String // Other info here, not related to AnotherA
    }
    let responseId: String
    let anotherA: AnotherA? // Optional
    let anotherB: AnotherB? // Optional
}
```

### Question:

How can I access `contactId` from `Container1` or `Container2` dynamically? (I tried the non dynamic approach with an extra function for each ContainerN struct with a switch inside but this is getting crazy because I have too many this structs, I already made some typos and forgot some cases, caused bugs,... and I imagine the reliable solution is "reflexion"?).

### Example:

For example, if `responseId` of `Container1` is "otherA" then I should look for `contactId` inside of property `otherA`. Since I have several types of Containers with different types of unrelated inner objects each one, solution should not be specific to Container1 nor Container2 it should work with any `ContainerBase`.

I implemented a dirty code but it causes a warning and cannot find to work it without generating one. Also I think this does not work reliably (This is for my iOS app but this strangely this does not work in linux Swift). Is this even possible? or it is a compiler glitch?

```
let c1 = Container1(
    responseId: "otherA",
    otherA: Container1.OtherA(contactId: "123", cats: ["figaro"]),
    otherB: nil)

c1.findContactId() // expected "123"
```

Ugly code ahead:

```
extension ContainerBase {
    func findContactId() -> String? {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        guard let tInnerRes = mirror.children.first(where: { $0.label == self.responseId })?.value else { return nil }

        // WARN: Conditional cast from 'Any' to 'Optional<Any>' always succeeds
        guard let maybeInnerRes = (tInnerRes as? Optional<Any>) else { return nil }

        guard let innerRes = maybeInnerRes else { return nil }
        let innerMirror = Mirror(reflecting: innerRes)
        let contactId = innerMirror.children.first(where: { $0.label == "contactId" })?.value as? String
        return contactId
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I follow everything you're doing exactly, but have you tried to create a Dictionary of structs in each container struct, with the key being the name of the struct?  That way, you can use the responseId as the key to lookup the struct you need to access?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed I could create a dictionary. If I create statically (before compiling) then I would need to create lots of lots of code since I have a large number of Container structs. If I create it dynamically (dictionary created at runtime automatically by some all-mighty logic) then I would fall in my current problem. I cannot access it correctly ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question (but better explained) in the swift forums and got [a great answer](https://forums.swift.org/t/using-mirror-to-access-value-of-a-property-of-an-optional-property-of-self/45533) from Alexis Schultz:

```
    func findContactId() -> String? {
        Mirror(reflecting: self)
            .children
            .first(where: { $0.label == responseId })
            .map(\.value)
            .flatMap(Mirror.init(reflecting:))?
            .children
            .first(where: { $0.label == "some" })
            .map(\.value)
            .flatMap(Mirror.init(reflecting:))?
            .children
            .first(where: { $0.label == "contactId" })?
            .value as? String
    }
```

Later, after seeing word "some" I realized that [Mirror's descendant function](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Mirror.swift#L428-L457) can do exactly the same job:

```
    func findContactId() -> String? {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        let value = mirror.descendant(responseId, "some", "contactId") as? String
        return value
    }
```